# Next level of abstraction up from a for loop?

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, nested-loops

Working in Python, but looking for a general structure.

I have a function that takes as input an array of length L (e.g., [0,0,0,...,0] with L semi-positive elements).  Each element of the input array has a positive maximum value, e.g., I have an array of length L, max_vals = [10,5,4,...,7].  I would like to iterate over all possible inputs to the function.

This can be done pretty easily using "generalized counting", but I wonder if there's a more graceful way to do this.  Specifically, I'd like some structure like:

```
meta_for vector in meta_range(max_vals):
    relevant_function( vector )
```

That is functionally equivalent to:

```
for i_1 in range(max_vals[0]):
    for i_2 in range(max_vals[1]):
        ...
            for i_L in range(max_vals[L-1]):
                relevant_function( [i_1, i_2, ..., i_L] )
```

The difficulty is that the number of nested for loops depends on L, and so can't be hardcoded.

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking to compute a [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set).

Comment: Yes. The simple way is recursion.

Comment: Could you give an example of input and desired output?

Comment: @MattBall, I'm having trouble seeing how they're the same.  I'm not trying to iterate over vectors of many different lengths, just to iterate over vectors with general length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools
max_vals = [3, 2]
for I in itertools.product(*[range(m) for m in max_vals]):
    print I
```

Prints

```
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(1, 0)
(1, 1)
(2, 0)
(2, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I really need to sit down with the itertools documentation; it really seems like that module should just get rolled in to the base language.